# Angular FormBuilder validator with new instance

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formbuilder

i hope everyone is ok. I search a lot for this question but without sucess. Im tryng to put validator on formbuilder with a instance of a class. Exemple below:

This is my component.ts file where i clear my formbuilder when component init;

```
  reset() {
    this.item_ctrl = new ItemController();
    this.item.itemForm = this.fb.group(
      this.item_ctrl.get //get the item in the controller
      //where to put validator?
      //how to validate separate variables?
    )
  }
```

Here is my controller

```
export class ItemController {
    _item: Item;

    constructor() {
        this._item = new Item();
    }

    public get get(): Item {
        return this._item;
    }
    public set(item: Item) {
        this._item = item;
    }
}
```

Here is my class

```
export class Item {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    //here where are my variables...
}
```

Hope you can understand.(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure, is that what you need but

control  - `this.myForm.addControl('newFormName', new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));`

formGroup - `const newGroupForm = this.fb.group({ id: [''], text: ['',Validators.required]}); this.myForm.addControl('yourGroupName',newGroupForm);`

Comment: Hi, i try this but isnt what im looking for. I want to know how to validate a variable that is inside the class. I dont know if it's possible, thanks for help

Comment: `this.yourForm.get('controllerName').updateValueAndValidity();` <--- checking validation manualy

`if(this.yourForm.get('controllerName').value != someCondition){
      this.yourForm.get('controllerName').setErrors('customError':true);` <--set custom error
    }